# Copy one image on top of the next, while retaining transparency

Tags: php, gd

I'm struggling with PHP's GDLib just a little bit here. I'm trying to overlay two .PNG images on top of eachother, which so far works fine.

The one problem I run into is that sometimes, the overlay image comes with a white background. I can make this transparent (using the `imagecolortransparent` function), but this transparency isn't saved when I copy this image onto a new one.

```
// Load the background image first

$background = imagecreatefrompng($this->background);

// Load the overlaying image next, and set white as a transparent color

$overlay = imagecreatefrompng($this->image);
imagecolortransparent($overlay, imagecolorallocate($overlay, 255, 255, 255));

// So far, this all works. But when I create a new image,
// and paste both $background and $overlay into it,
// $overlay loses transparency and reverts to a white fill.

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(16, 16);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

imagecopyresampled($image, $background, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16);
imagecopyresampled($image, $overlay, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16);
@mkdir(dirname($file), 0777, true);
imagepng($image, $file);

// The new $image is now mostly white. The transparency on $overlay
// was lost, meaning that the $background image is completely invisible.
```

How can I keep the transparency when copying  `$overlay` into a new image?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your sample code. PHP documentation for `imagesavealpha()` says "You have to unset alphablending (`imagealphablending($im, false)`), to use it." Also have you tried `imagecopyresized()` instead of `imagecopyresampled()`?

Comment: @miken32 I've done a little more experimenting. I've fixed the syntax error in the example (just a copy paste error, it's not there in the actual script obviously). I also removed `imageSaveAlpha()` and turned my `imageCopyResampled()` into `imageCopyResized()`. The end result is that the overlay now is, in fact, transparent, but the resulting image is not. This now has a white background.

Comment: I think you still need the call to `imageSaveAlpha()` before you output with `imagepng()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$photo_to_paste = "photo_to_paste.png";
$white_image = "white_image.png";

$im = imagecreatefrompng($white_image);
$im2 = imagecreatefrompng($photo_to_paste);

imagecopy($im, $im2, (imagesx($im) / 2) - (imagesx($im2) / 2), (imagesy($im) / 2) - (imagesy($im2) / 2), 0, 0, imagesx($im2), imagesy($im2));

// Save alpha for the destination image.
imagesavealpha($im, true);
$trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

// Save final image after placing one on another image
imagepng($im, "output.png", 0);

imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($im2);
```